# Define an array just once and change it without defining it again in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to define an array in a line of the program, for example, as follows:

```
var a = [2,5];
//In the next steps, I want to increase the array elements as follows:
a[0] += 2;
a[1] += 2;
//And I want the array to increase intermittently at the output of the program, as follows:
a = [4,7]
a = [6,9]
a = [8,11]
//....
```

But in reality this does not happen because in the first line of the program, the array is defined again and again.

And the output is always as follows: `a = [4,7];`

Is there a way to initialize the `a` array as `[2,5]` only once?

Comment: you have defined `a` only once. what is the problem with reassigning?

Comment: No, it is not.....
The program is constantly running...
Each time it reaches the first line, the value of a is reloaded, which I do not want to happen...
In fact, I want the array elements to always increase, but by redefining the array in the first row and setting it as [2,5] again and again, this is not possible...

Comment: You need to provide more information about the context this code is running in. You say *"The program is constantly running... Each time it reaches the first line, ..."* but you are not explaining how/why that is.

Answer (score 0):

Here, I use a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures). The array is created once and modified each time you call `increase()`:

```js
function createIncreaseFunction()
{
  const a = [2,5];
  function increase()
  {
    a[0] += 2;
    a[1] += 2;
    return a;
  }
  return increase;
}
let increase = createIncreaseFunction();
console.log(increase()); // [4,7]
console.log(increase()); // [6,9]
console.log(increase()); // [8,11]

// increase() modifies the values in the array,
// but the same array is returned each time:
console.log(increase() === increase()); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this.

- This is a very simple way if you want to increase it a fixed number of times:

```
    let a = [2,5];
    for (let i=0;i<5;i++) {
        a=a.map(element=>element+2);
        console.log(a);
    }
```

- Using a nested function/closure [as shown in Lonnie Best's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71487293/define-an-arrey-just-once-and-change-that-without-defining-again-in-javascript/71487460#71487460)
- Or you can also use a generator function:

```
    function * arrayIncreaser(initialArray, num) {
      let a = initialArray;
      while (true) {
        a = a.map(element=>element+num)
        yield a;
      }
    }
    
    const increaser = arrayIncreaser([2,5],2)
    console.log(increaser.next().value);
    console.log(increaser.next().value);
    console.log(increaser.next().value);
```